# Does the priority period of the Paris Convention start with the actual or the effective filing date of a patent application?

Tags: paris-convention

I believe the Paris Convention would allow me to file a patent application in country B within a year of filing the same application in country A.  But does that year begin with the actual filing date or the effective filing date of the application in country A?  Suppose a file a provisional in the US on December 31 2019, then a non-provisional that claims the benefit of the provisional on December 31 2020, then a continuation-in-part of the non-provisional on December 31 2023, while the non-provisional is still pending.  Can I file in Germany before the end of 2020, 2021 or 2024?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In article 4 C the [Paris Convention](https://wipolex.wipo.int/en/text/288514) says

> 2) These periods shall start from the date of filing of the first application; the day of filing shall not be included in the period.

It is the first filing of an application on the subject matter. There are circumstances where a second application can be used if the first filed is withdrawn.